# How to apply loop to extract contents from "DIV" tag while using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, loops, tags, beautifulsoup, textwrangler

i have recently found a very neat way of web scraping using bs4 that has a really nice organized structure to it. let us say this is our html code:

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <a href="www.yelloaes.com">'hi'</a>
  </div>
  <div class ="c">
    <p><a href="www.bb.com">'hi again'</a></p>
    <div class="d">
      <p>'well this final'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <a href="www.yelloaes1.com">'hi1'</a>
  </div>
  <div class ="c">
    <p><a href="www.bb1.com">'hi again1'</a></p>
    <div class="d">
      <p>'well this final1'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now i am assuming `<div class="a">` is our parent tag and we will suck info out of this tag, now that means i have to loop through this to extract info from all the page .

but because i was having a hard time understanding BeautifulSoup i did a test run with a python code to extract the info from the first iteration of this `<div class= "a">`

my code is like this :

```
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
find_hi =      soup.find('div',{'class':'a'}).div.text
find_hi-again =soup.find('div',{'class':'a'}).find_all('div')[1].p.text
find_final    =soup.find('div',{'class':'a'}).find('div',{'class':'d'}).text

print(find_hi , find_hi-again , find_final)

#output comes as (it worked !!!)
hi , hi again  , this is final
```

Note: I really want to stick with this one so please no completely new ways of scraping. now i **can't seem to loop on all the page** .
i tried this for looping but does not show the result i want to see:

```
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
#To have a list of all div tags having this class
scraping  = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'a'})
for i in scraping:
    find_hi =      i.div.text
    find_hi-again =i.find_all('div')[1].p.text
    find_final    =i.find('div',{'class':'d'}).text

print(find_hi , find_hi-again , find_final)
```

please help in looping ?

Comment: What is the result that is shown?

Comment: it is showing a result but it is not showing the different elements but is showing repeated elements from the same tag      like ,*** hi , hi again , well this final , hi  , hi again , well this final ** instead of **hi , hi again , well this  final  , hi1 , hi again1 , well this final1 **

Comment: Share the url if possible and what you expect as output, your current code make little sense.

Comment: i want to print the contents from expedia.com like hotel name , ratings etc , when i inspected the website i found a pattern of div tags with a unique class objects for each hotel listed . Now i used **find** not **find_all** so to print the desired the things from the first div tag , my question is simply how to loop for each hotels  ?

Comment: From memory expedia is heavily reliant on javascript so you won't get the source using anything other than something that can run javascript

Comment: yaa @PadraicCunningham i did not at last found what i was looking for in expedia.com but i did manage to scrap coursera.com and udacity.com ,

Answer (score 0):

You code works fine for me, except for the syntax error: `find_hi-again` is not a valid variable name.

```
divs  = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'a'})
for i in divs:
    find_hi = i.div.text.strip()
    find_hi_again = i.find_all('div')[1].p.text.strip()
    find_final = i.find('div',{'class':'d'}).text.strip()

    print(find_hi , find_hi_again , find_final)

## (u"'hi'", u"'hi again'", u"'well this final'")
## (u"'hi1'", u"'hi again1'", u"'well this final1'")
```

Comment: please try on large real page and tell me if it works  because it is not working for me . and yaa i made that name up i know that it throws an error.

Comment: thanks for the answer i checked it works i guess it does not works on some sites i tried on expedia and makemytrip and it was not working but on other sites it worked